# Different between transient final of primitive type and transient final wrapper type

Tags: java

What is different between `transient final int` and `transient final Integer`.

Using `int`:

```
transient final int a = 10;
```

Before Serialization:

```
a = 10
```

After serialization:

```
a = 10
```

Using `Integer`:

```
transient final Integer a = 10;
```

Before Serialization:

```
a = 10
```

After serialization:

```
a = null
```

full code:

```
public class App implements Serializable {
    transient final Integer transientFinal = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                "logInfo.out"));
        App a = new App();
        System.out.println("Before Serialization ...");
        System.out.println("transientFinalString = " + a.transientFinal);
        o.writeObject(a);
        o.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // deal with exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                "logInfo.out"));
        App x = (App) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("After Serialization ...");
        System.out.println("transientFinalString = " + x.transientFinal);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // deal with exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you do Serialization? I don't see any in your code.

Comment: What is the supposed purpose of marking something both `transient` and `final`?

Comment: This might help – http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/can-transient-variables-be-declared-as-final-or-static/0.

Comment: Hi @Gedrox, I just read this article before posted this question. In the article everything worked fine, but I tried to use Integer instead of String, it didn't work

Comment: Interesting behavior (though @biziclop is right). I wonder whether `transient final int a = (int)System.currentMillis();` still is primarily treated as final. That `transient` on a final object has an effect is the remarkable thing. Like: `Integer a = deserialize(); /* no can do as final: */ a = Integer.valueOf(10);`

Comment: I can guess that because of autoboxing the `Integer transientFinal = 10` isn't treated as a constant expression. See http://www.coderanch.com/t/329474/java/java/final-static-Integer-considered-constant – "definition of compile-time constant expressions can only be applied to primitives and Strings".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in article

http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/can-transient-variables-be-declared-as-final-or-static/0

making field transient will prevent its serialization with one exception:

> There is just one exception to this rule, and it is when the transient final field member is initialized to a `constant expression` as those defined in the [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). Hence, field members declared this way would hold their constant value expression even after deserializing the object.

If you will visit mentioned JSL you will know that

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of `primitive type` or a `String`

But `Integer` is not primitive type, and it is not String so it is not considered as candidate of constant expression so its value will not stay after serialization.

Demo:

```
class SomeClass implements Serializable {
    public transient final int a = 10;
    public transient final Integer b = 10;
    public transient final String c = "foo";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(sc);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                bos.toByteArray()));
        SomeClass sc2 = (SomeClass) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(sc2.a);
        System.out.println(sc2.b);
        System.out.println(sc2.c);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
null
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Only constant expressions will be assigned to the fields after deserialization. And the `Integer` cannot be expressed as constant expression, only primitive types and Strings can be according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28.

And the reason the `final int` is *keeping* its value is specified in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3:

```
Even then, there are a number of complications. If a final field is initialized 
to a compile-time constant expression (§15.28) in the field declaration, changes 
to the final field may not be observed, since uses of that final field are 
replaced at compile time with the value of the constant expression.
```

Thus usages of this field are replaced with constants in compilation time and cannot be influenced by serialization in runtime.

Comment: I'm wondering why serialization touches transient fields at all. I would at least expect `a==0` after deserialization.

Comment: Can't find any reference in Oracle docs where this would be specified. I guess this behavior is defined deeper than serialization layer. I guess the fields with constant expressions are initialized even before construction of the object, maybe stored with class definition.